# New to python (and programming) need some advice on arranging things diagonally

Tags: python

I'm finishing up an assignment for my 1035 computer science lab and the last thing I need to do is arrange inputted numbers in a diagonal line.
I've tried things like:

```
print (\tnum2)
```

and like this:

```
print ('\t'num2)
```

but I can't figure out how to do it. I've looked through my programming book, but have been unable to find an explanation on how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

strings in python can be concatenated using the + sign. For example

```
print(' ' + str(a))
```

will give the following output for a=1

```
 1
```

Notice the single blank space before 1. The function str(a) returns the integer a in string format. This is because print statement can only print strings, not integers.

Also

```
print(' ' * i)
```

prints i blank spaces. If i = 10, then 10 blank spaces will be printed.

So, the solution to the question can be:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print((' ' * i) + str(a[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example that prints items in a list on a diagonal line:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     print("\t" * i + str(l[i]))
... 
1
    2
        3
            4
                5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using .format

```
nome = input("nome:")
a = " "
b = len(nome)

for i in range(b):
    print ("{0} {1}".format(a * i, nome[i]))

print ("\n next \n")
c=b
for i in range(b):
    print ("{0} {1}".format(a * c, nome[i]))
    c = c-1
```

this give diagonal increasing or decreasing