# I cannot figure out how to manipulate strings in a couple different ways

Tags: python, string

I need to write a script that modifies an inputted string in these patterns (but without the dashes. those are just in there to format properly):

```
enter a string: dinosaurs

-d

--i

---n

----o

-----s

------a

-------u

--------r

---------s

-d

--i

---n

----o

-----s

----a

---u

--r

-s



-d-------s

--i------r

---n---u

----o-a

-----s
```

I don't even know where to start with this one.

Comment: What's the explanation behind the last one?

Comment: Code formatting works for this a lot better than hyphens. It's the button with the braces on it.

Comment: you need to start by getting the length of the input - there's the function `len()` for that. then you can start counting in a loop to decide how many spaces to put for the proper indentation.

Comment: Are you saying you want to pad the n'th letter with n + 1 spaces?

Comment: the last one can be solved similarly: find the length of the word, find the middle of the word, go from left and right towards the middle in a loop and decide by how many spaces to separate the letters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to python (and programming) need some advice on arranging things diagonally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947996/new-to-python-and-programming-need-some-advice-on-arranging-things-diagonally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll split this into three sections, one for each format. First, start off with your imports and read your word from standard input.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import math

word = sys.argv[1]
```

#### 1. Margin increasing with length of string

```
for i, character in enumerate(word):
    print(i * " ", character, sep='')
```

#### 2. Margin decreases as distance to middle of string increases

We create a function to compute the distance from the ends of the word and use it to add the correct number of spaces accordingly.

```
distance = lambda i: len(word) / 2 - int(math.fabs((len(word) / 2) - i))
for i, character in enumerate(word):
    print(distance(i) * " ", character, sep='')
```

#### 3. Word displays as a triangle with the middle of the word at the bottom.

For the last one, we have to test if the word is an odd number of characters and add an offset of one if it does. We use this offset to align the middle characters correctly. We also redefine the `distance` function to indicate the distance from the middle of the word instead of from the end of the word.

```
distance = lambda i: int(math.fabs((len(word) / 2.) - i)) - 1
if len(word) % 2 == 1:
    offset = 1
else:
    offset = 0

for i in range(len(word) / 2 + offset):
    if i == len(word) - i - 1:
        print((i - offset) * " ", word[i])
    else:
        print(i * " ", word[i], (2 * distance(i) + offset) * " ", word[len(word) - i - 1], sep='')
```

Edit: Here is the output from running the program with "dinosaurs" as the provided input.

```
d
 i
  n
   o
    s
     a
      u
       r
        s

d
 i
  n
   o
    s
   a
  u
 r
s

d       s
 i     r
  n   u
   o a
    s
```

Comment: seriously, using lambda? The op cannot figure out how to print letters with spaces and you are using code like this? I have also already answered using enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to index each letter:

```
inputted="dinosaurs"

In [25]: for i,c in enumerate(inputted,start=1): # set start to 1 instead of the default 0
            print " "* i + c ' 

     d
      i
       n
        o
         s
          a
           u
            r
             s
```

This should help you figure out the second part of your question also.